# Mixing REST and RPC logic in Web API 2 project

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, rpc

With web API 2 and the recent addition of [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) gave me the idea of creating a central API application for our corporate needs.

But my problem is that pure REST approach feels somewhat limiting to our enterprise data exchange needs.

So after reading [THIS](http://encosia.com/rest-vs-rpc-in-asp-net-web-api-who-cares-it-does-both/) i decided to follow a mix approach:

Have some controllers as pure REST and some in RPC style.

A nice idea from the article about routing is *(changed it a little for RpcApi to add {id} placeholder)*:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "RestApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "RpcApi",
  routeTemplate: "services/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

What i need to decide on and need your advice is:

**Separation between REST and RPC style / Categorization of domain operations**:

Would it be a good solution to create 2 Areas in my Web API? One for RPC and one for REST?

But then how i would categorize furhter (one level) my domain operations? (ERP,CRM,Payroll). Initially i thought that these would be appropriate areas.

Another idea would be to create a physical separation for controllers by separate folders under controller folder, although this would mean to have unique controller names as sub folders are irrelevant for the framework.

**Additional Info:**

Interesting opinion for [organising ASP.NET MVC/Web API projects](http://douglastarr.com/keep-your-asp-dot-net-mvc-projects-more-organized-with-partial-classes/)

Any ideas?

Comment: I can see a need for incorporating functions outwith the standard REST CRUD pattern, but I'd be careful about putting them into separate controllers/folders. Future contributors may not share your opinion on the distinction between REST/RPC, and by that point your functionality is going to be scattered to the winds.
Your 'Additional Info' link gives me the heebie jeebies. Using partial classes to divvy up class functionality has generally led me down a path of indecipherability. Trying to remember/track down bits of classes organised in weird and wonderful ways is not my idea of a good time.